# how to change date format in cursor from 'May 4 2013 2:28AM' to '2013-05-04 02:28:34.000'

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How do I change the date formatting in a cursor? My table stores the date format like '2013-05-04 02:28:34.000'. When I use a cursor it returns like 'May 4 2013 2:28AM'.

In my cursor I am using @date as createdate:

```
@date as varchar(50)
```

My update query:

```
Update [OITM_clone] set DB01RKD_1='2' where ItemCode='CKC3130756'
and Createdate=@date
```

The query does not execute because of the different date formats of the table and the cursor.

Comment: Show your cursor code - why is this a string at any point? Why does the stored data have any "format" - you're not storing datetime values as strings, are you? Are you checking the value using PRINT? Stop doing that, it applies regional string formatting that is unrelated. Are you sure you even need a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your date variable @date must be a datetime, also variable where you stored the value cursor must be datetime

In this way, when you treat these variables you can compare them without problems.

About a more complete answer please post your SQL code.